# Data Variable Error "filter cannot complete because of an unknown error"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, data-merge, error

[image: =multiple box in same sheet]

Hello, I'm a beginner in design, and I'm having trouble with applying the data variable function in Adobe Illustrator. I've searched extensively but couldn't find a solution. When I try to apply it to multiple boxes with different text in the same sheet, I get an "filter cannot complete because of an unknown error." It works when I apply it to a single box, but I want to use it in all boxes to save time. Can you help me with this issue? picture is attached for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a [bug introduced into Illustrator in version 26.3.1.](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/the-filter-cannot-complete-because-of-an-unknown-error/td-p/12969795)

The feature has been broken since thenin all supported versions of Illustrator.

The problem started with Illustrator 26.3, and remains unaddressed in the latest version available as of today (28.3.)

Adobe doesn't support older versions, however if you open a support ticket with them you may be able to get a link to an older version which doesn't have this bug.